# Warning: Design contains 1 high-fanout nets. A fanout number of 1000 will be used for delay calculations involving these nets. (TIM-134)

Tags: vhdl, synthesis

I'm having this warning while syn. a vhdl code with synopsys design compiler.
How can I eliminate this warning ?

Answer (score 3):

It's a useful warning : and it's a warning not an error : why do you want to eliminate it?

1) Is the high fanout expected? If not, find out why it's occurring, and if it turns out to come from a mistake, (I wanted one register, not 32!) fix it.
2) If the high fanout is real and you can tolerate the slow timings as a result, then increase the fanout limit in your synthesis tool.
3) If the high fanout is real and you can NOT tolerate the slow timings, then check that the tool is replicating the signal enough times to reduce the fanout and improve timings. It will report the duplicated signals somewhere.

4) If your process requires that you remove every synthesis warning (and I have never worked anywhere that is the case) then replicate the signals yourself (and add synthesis attributes to prevent their removal!) to reduce fanout enough to eliminate the warning. 
But that leads to messy, hard to maintain designs.

Answer (score 0):

Design Compiler computes the delays of high-fanout nets with a simpler model to delimit the computation effort. That can reduce the accuracy of timing analysis on the relevant nets, which mostly carry reset or scan signals.

If timing constraints have enough margins or delay of the net is not so critical, the warning can be ignored. In case STA is run with full accuracy after synthesis, it's already safe.

If accuracy is more important than the runtime of synthesis, `high_fanout_net_threshold` variable can be set to a greater value. Simply setting it to `0` guarantees that all net delays will be computed with full accuracy.